# Is this Linear Transformation Isomorphic? Given that a Matrix is Nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, nilpotence

Given a matrix in $M_{n \times n}$ which is nilpotent. Prove that the Linear Transformation $T:M_{n \times n} \rightarrow M_{n \times n}$ given by $T(X) = X -NX$ is an isomorphism.

Shouldn't be answered with Eigenvalues and Eigenvector, it should only be answered using matrices, vector spaces, Linear transformations.

Comment: I saw that earlier, the issue is that the problem shouldn't be answered with Eigenvalues and Eigenvector, it should only be answered using matrices, vector spaces, Linear transformations. Any Ideas?

Comment: @Musicue If that is the case then you should edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Done, sorry I'm new to this. Thanks for the advice.